# Tensorflow MeanSquaredError doens't work on one number

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function, mean-square-error

I am trying calculate the loss of a network with tensorflow mean squared error, but for some reason it doesn't work if the input tensors only have one number. How should do this instead.

Here is some code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()

a = loss(y_true=tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]), y_pred=tf.constant([2.0, 2.0, 4.0]))
print(a)

a = loss(y_true=tf.constant(1.0, dtype=tf.float32), y_pred=tf.constant(2.0, dtype=tf.float32)) #this is where the error occurs.
print(a)
```

error

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid reduction dimension (-1 for input with 0 dimension(s) [Op:Mean]

Comment: you need to pass an array:
`a = loss(y_true=tf.constant([1.0], dtype=tf.float32), y_pred=tf.constant([2.0], dtype=tf.float32))`

Comment: You're right that worked.